# Tabbing outside of handsontable cells

Tags: handsontable

We have a button at the bottom of handsontable. When the user tabs in the last cell, can we select the button instead of wrapping back to the first cell?

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpusarla/9nny9tye/)

```js
var data = [
  ["", "Ford", "Volvo", "Toyota", "Honda"],
  ["2014", 10, 11, 12, 13],
  ["2015", 20, 11, 14, 13],
  ["2016", 30, 15, 12, 13]
];

var container = document.getElementById('example');
var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
  data: data,
  minSpareRows: 1,
  rowHeaders: true,
  colHeaders: true,
  autoWrapRow: true,
  autoWrapColumn: true
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handsontable/0.14.1/handsontable.full.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handsontable/0.14.1/handsontable.full.js"></script>
<form>
  <div id='example'></div>
  <br />
  <input type="button" value="Save"></input>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is capture the event, in your case `.on('beforekeydown')`, and check for the tab key. If pressed, check what cell the hot instance is currently on using `hot.getSelected()` and if it is the last cell, switch the focus to whatever button you want. Here is some detail of the code:

```
Handsontable.Dom.addEvent(containerTag, 'keydown', function(e) {
  // On Tab, go to external button if last cell
  if (e.keyCode === 9 && hotInstance) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var selection = hotInstance.getSelected();
    var rowIndex = selection[0];
    var colIndex = selection[1];
    if (rowIndex == lastRow && colIndex == lastCol) {
       hotInstance.deselect();
       buttonJquerySelector.focus();
    }
  }
});
```

I haven't tested this code but this is more or less what you should be trying to do.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if there is an alternate way  to intercept the tabMoves option but looks like none. We are going to try the above.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fix that work on multiple tables. Place a button inside the container and add a class name which make the button positioned outside the point of view. Works in 6.2.2

```
Handsontable.hooks.add('beforeKeyDown', function (event) {
    // On Tab, go to external button if last cell
    if (event.keyCode !== 9) {
        return;
    }

    var sel = this.getSelected();
    var lastRow = this.countRows() - 1;
    var lastCol = this.countCols() - 1;

    if ((!event.shiftKey && sel[0][0] === lastRow && sel[0][1] === lastCol) || (event.shiftKey && sel[0][0] === 0 && sel[0][1] === 0)) {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();

         var el = $(this.getInstance()).get(0).rootElement;
        // Focus the activator button first -> otherwise, if the user has not tabbed into the table, it wouldn't skip to the next form element
        var hotActivators = el.getElementsByTagName('button');
        if (hotActivators.length > 0) {
            hotActivators[0].focus();
        }

        this.unlisten();
        this.deselectCell();
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.hotActivatorButton {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 100%;
    right: 100%;
}
```